# How to enter recovery mode after cyanogen mod 11 in xiaomi redmi 1s ??

Tags: cyanogenmod

After installing the cyanogenMod 11 in my xiaomi redmi 1s I found that there is no recovery option but then I switched off my phone and I try to enter in recovery mode by pressing "Volume up +Power buttton"  but I could not entered in recovery mode and I could not install the Google Apps package without recovery.... Please help me!!!

Comment: Well, that's something weird I would say you should be getting inside the bootloader just by pressing an holding volume up+power and way try going to the settings>developer settings>check advanced reboot and then again try rebooting your device in the recovery mode and see if that helps you ?

Comment: @PeterCarlos this worked perfectly on our case. Thanks a lot.